# Divs appearing everywhere in post content

Tags: posts, hooks, html, actions

Whenever somebody writes a post on our site, the Paly Voice (http://palyvoice.com) there are automatically a lot of `<div>` elements created. This is bad for layout, since we have a style that applies to divs that we don't want to apply to story styles.

Is there a way to remove the automatic div insertion? If not, can I add a function hook to parse the post and remove them before saving to the DB?

Edit: Example here: http://palyvoice.com/2012/08/22/new-grade-reports-to-be-mailed-home-every-four-weeks-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first should find out where the divs are coming from, since that's not normal behavior. Could be from a plugin or - as Damien said - copy-pasting a text from Word.

To remove the divs you can do a simple

```
str_replace(array('<div>', '</div>'), '', $content)
```

either before storing the text in the database (by hooking on `save_post`), or before displaying it on the site (by adding a filter on `the_content`).

EDIT: I was wrong, you don't hook on `save_post`, but instead you filter on `wp_insert_post_data`. This function below should work:

```
function remove_divs($data) {
    $filteredContent = str_replace(array('<div>', '</div>'), '', $data['post_content']);
    $data['post_content'] = $filteredContent;

    return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'remove_divs', 99);
```

Put this in your functions.php

Comment: Where can I put this in my files to hook into save_post? Then I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: Check out my edit, that should work for removing any divs before the post get saved to the database.

Comment: In which file do you put this?

Comment: `functions.php` in your theme folder.

Comment: What does the 99 mean?

Comment: It's the priority of the function. It comes in to play when different functions runs in the same hook. 99 probably isn't necessary here, you could experiment with it if you think it would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1):

Is the person using cut n paste from word? This can add a lot of horrible extra  elements.

In the toolbar for Wordpress there is a button for inserting directly from word .. This should help.